# Where is this +y-izing habit coming from?

Tags: etymology, slang

Like laptop -> lappy, napkin -> nappy, football -> footy

Is this just an Aussie thingy?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an Australian thing, but a  word formation  generally used with common, familiar nouns
( see -y suffix usage below)

***[Lappy:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lappy)*** , for instance is made from the first part of the original term *lap*top, *lap* and adding the suffix y.

> - informal,(*chiefly British*) a laptop:

[Laptop](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Laptop&searchmode=none): (Etymonline)

> - also lap-top, as a type of portable computer, 1984, from lap (n.) + top (1), on model of desktop.

Same for ***[Footy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/footy)*** (noun) :

> - (British Informal)  term for football.
> - Australian /NZ informal term for rugby or Australian rules.

***[-y](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-y&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (3):

> - suffix in pet proper names (such as Johnny, Kitty), first recorded in Scottish c. 1400; according to OED it became frequent in English 15c.-16c. Extension to surnames seems to date from c. 1940. ***Use with common nouns seems to have begun in Scottish with laddie (1546) and become popular in English due to Burns' poems,*** but the same formation appears to be represented much earlier in baby and puppy.

Comment: The rarer -ie variant (given by Collins for _footie_; another example is _ciggie_) seems to indicate that this is driven by the spoken language. The suffix _is_ a softening device, used to indicate affection. At grammar school, 'Smithy / Smithie'; 'Jonesie'; 'Aspy' (Aspinall) etc sounded much better than the stark surnames. // 'Where is this ... coming from?' is perhaps not the best way of phrasing the question, given that _Johnny_ is recorded from 1400. // Excellent answer.

Comment: I'm curious now as to whether this is more prevalent, in general, in British or Australian English than in American English. In the US, the same phenomenon exists for personal names, but maybe not so much for other things (?). (Dunno how this could be checked, except perhaps by getting a count of dictionary etc. entries.) Also: is it the same phenomenon whether the result is a term of endearment or is a shortened form?